# How To Work In The Background On Android 13?

Tags: android, background-process, background-service, foreground-service, android-13

I built app that do polling to the server via HTTP requests every 2 seconds,
and now I want to make it work even in the background when the screen is black (user press on lock screen button) because when its **minimized **its work. I testing the app on Samsung and I **TURNOFF **the battery optimization for the app and added the app to "never sleeping apps" list via phone settings, and still I not able to make the polling if the phone in lock screen.

I develop medical emergency app and I need to work always, I tried to add FOREGROUND SERVICE its solve the case when the app in the background(minimized) but not when the app in lock screen with black screen.

So my question is there any way to make polling to the server every 2 seconds even if the app in the background(lock screen), I want that the app will continue to work in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found soultion that work even in DOZE (lock screen) mode, Foreground Service does not **guarantee background work**,
Foreground Service take care of Process Death in Android - that was not my case.

The solution is to use Alarm Manager with setAlarmClock, Foreground Service not required.

```
    private fun setAlarmClock() {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val intervalMillis = 5000L

    val alarmClockInfo = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalMillis, alarmIntent)
    alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, alarmIntent)
}
```

Comment: Beware of using alarm clock for apps on Google Play.  There is a new restricted permission requirement for Exact Alarm API, stating that apps must only declare this permission if their core functionality requires an exact alarm. Apps declaring the new restricted permission that do not meet these criteria will not be permitted on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

**yes u can**
Use alarm manager or show notifications that the app is running in the background.

**Service**

```
// LifecycleService with MutableLiveData If you want to use mvvm
 //You can exchange it for the service

    public class AlarmService extends LifecycleService {
       
        public static MutableLiveData<String> status =new MutableLiveData<>();
        private Notification.Builder builder;
        private NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
 
    
       
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
    
            
    
            notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel("channel","channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    
           
            startForeground(500,notification());
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    
           
    
             Handler handler = new Handler();
             Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "run: ");
                        // your Code
                     status.postValue("run");//change status If you want to send data to an activity
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);//change this 1000ms
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000) //change this 1000ms;
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    
    
       
    
    
      
        public Notification notification(){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,getClass());
            @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
            PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getService(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    
            builder =new Notification.Builder(this,"channel");
            builder.setContentText("The service runs in the forground");
            builder.setContentTitle("Service is running");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_send);
    
    
            NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            return builder.build();
        }
       
    }
```

**Actvity**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName =getPackageName();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);

            }

}
    

     Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmService.class);
                           startService(intent);
    
        AlarmService.status.observe(this, s -> {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
              });
```

**Don't forget in manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />


     <service
                android:name=".AlarmService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:label="Alarm"
                android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: If the time is near. Like every second alarm is not recommended

Comment: Yes I need to do request to the server every 2 seconds, seems its not the right solution for me, thank you any way

Comment: I've edited it, take a look

Comment: thank you, but i tried the turn off the battery optimization and to use foreground service and it didn't work, I found another solution that worked for me using Alarm Manager.